# sending Email with Attachment xpages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

this is my sample coding for sending email with attachment. The content of word is not send correctly.

[image] attachment is using "file upload"

```
//  write mail
var setdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("System Setting", "");
var server = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDBSvr");
var dname = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDbPath");
var web = setdoc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress");


var maildoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Subject","Test Send Mail");
session.setConvertMime(false);
var stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText("<html><body>");

stream.writeText("<p>Dear " + "[person]" + ",</p>");
stream.writeText("<p>Attached item is an image of </p>");
stream.writeText("<p> ***THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE - PLEASE DO NOT REPLY DIRECTLY TO THIS EMAIL***</p>");
stream.writeText("</body></html>");

var body = maildoc.createMIMEEntity("Body");

var Att= document1.getDocument(true).getFirstItem("Attachment");
maildoc.copyItem(Att,"Body")    //  try adding an item

body.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html;charset=UTF-8", 1725);
stream.close();
maildoc.closeMIMEEntities(true);
session.setConvertMime(true);

maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo","TestUser1@devsvr1.pcs.com.my");      
maildoc.send();
```

The result come out is only the attachment field without any text value inside. I not sure which part of it is wrong.

**sample Result screen:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Recommended Mime style

```
var HTMLMail = function() {
...
}   
var mail = new HTMLMail();
mail.setTo("TestUser1@devsvr1.pcs.com.my")
//mail.addFileAttachment(result);
mail.setSubject("Test Send Mail");
mail.addHTML("<h1>Hi!</h1>");
mail.addHTML("<table><tbody><tr><td>contents in a table here</td></tr></tbody></table>");
mail.send();
```

Comment: how are you going with this Desmond? have you got it working? need anymore help?

Comment: Problem solve in rich text method...if possible wish to know how Mime method link with [xpages] core control : file upload ~

Answer (score 4):

IBM Notes/Domino has 2 ways to show 'pretty words and pictures'

- RichText
- MIME

You should only use one or the other, but here you are actually mixing both the different types.

Above, when you copy the Attachment Item, you are actually adding the first 'Body' item, you can see it's type 'RichText'.
Then we you createMimeEntity you are creating the second 'Body' item, and it's type is 'MimePart' (it is probably showing second because the Mime is not applied until CloseMimeEntities)
So now you have 2 Body items with different parts. You are seeing the 'RichText' attachment in Notes because it is first listed item.

What you actually need to do is create the correct multipart mime structure.
If you want a bit more information about mime, I a blog post on my site which explains it a little bit more, including some info about the correct mime structure.
http://camerongregor.com/2016/04/21/webmail-ui-you-must-learn-about-mime/

If you haven't seen it yet there is an XSnippet by Mark Leusink which has a demo of creating a mime email using SSJS. I don't use this myself as I don't use SSJS but it might be useful to you as it should handle most of this mime manipulation for you. 
https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime

Comment: don't really understand how  XSnippet by Mark Leusink  using mime attach an item? For Richtextitem, i think appendRTItem will be posible to do attachment

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318235/xpages-how-to-append-prepend-text-to-a-richtext-field/12329718#12329718

i follow the link one is a rich text item, which working

Comment: look at about line 244. Don't think about adding the 'item' but think about adding the 'embedded objects' so for each embedded object you want to add, you can do what it is doing at about line 244.
Which is: Get the inputstream of the embedded object and use it to create a mimeentity

Comment: Definite answer: Don't bother trying NotesItems here. You want to compose your message as complete mime construct and send it out that way.

Answer (score 0):

My coding with reference using rich-text style :

```
var setdoc:NotesDocument = database.getProfileDocument("System Setting", "");
var server = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDBSvr");
var dname = setdoc.getItemValueString("MailDbPath");
var web = setdoc.getItemValueString("InternetAddress");

var maildoc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument();
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Form", "Memo");
maildoc.replaceItemValue("Subject","Test Send Mail");
session.setConvertMime(false);
var stream = session.createStream();
stream.writeText("<html><body>");

stream.writeText("<p>Dear <b>" + "person" + "</b>,</p>");

stream.writeText("<p> ***THIS IS AN AUTOMATED MESSAGE - PLEASE DO NOT REPLY DIRECTLY TO THIS EMAIL***</p>");

stream.writeText("</body></html>");

var tmpDoc:NotesDocument = maildoc.getParentDatabase().createDocument();     
var mime:NotesMIMEEntity = tmpDoc.createMIMEEntity("myBody");
var addRt:NotesMIMEEntity = maildoc.getMIMEEntity("addBody");
var Att:NotesRichTextItem = document1.getDocument(true).getFirstItem("Attachment");
if(addRt != null && @Length(addRt.getContentAsText().trim()) > 28) {
    stream.writeText('<font size="2" face="sans-serif">');      // Enforce "simiilar" font type/size...
    stream.writeText(addRt.getContentAsText());
    stream.writeText('</font>');
}

mime.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html", NotesMIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
var prevMime = session.isConvertMime();
session.setConvertMime(true);
tmpDoc.closeMIMEEntities(true,"myBody");
var rt:NotesRichTextItem = maildoc.getFirstItem("Body");
var body = null;
if (rt != null) {
    body = rt.copyItemToDocument(tmpDoc,"Body");
    rt.remove();
}
rt = maildoc.createRichTextItem("Body");
var rtMime:NotesRichTextItem = tmpDoc.getFirstItem("myBody");
rt.appendRTItem(rtMime);
if(Att != null) {
    if(addRt == null) rt.addNewLine(1);
    rt.appendRTItem(Att);
    Att.remove();
}
if(body != null) {
    rt.addNewLine(2);
    rt.appendRTItem(body);
}
if(addRt != null) {
    addRt.remove();
    addRt.recycle();
}



stream.close();
maildoc.closeMIMEEntities(true);
session.setConvertMime(true);

maildoc.replaceItemValue("SendTo","TestUser1@devsvr1.pcs.com.my");      
maildoc.send();
```